# Adding a space to the beginning of every cell in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column of data, and I would like to simply add a space to the beginning of each cell. How can I do this?

It should be like this:

Original:

```
1
2
3
4
```

After:

```
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

Comment: Voting to close this question as very unclear in its current form. Are you simply wanting to change the _appearance_ of the cells (if so, use `left justify` and then `increase indent` - both these tools usually appear as buttons on the Home ribbon bar) or are you wanting to change the numeric values to text preceded with one space character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the data is in column A. In an empty column enter this formula in the first row:

```
=" "&A1
```

- Copy down as far as the data in column A.
- Copy the result of the formulas
- Use paste special > Values to paste the data into column A
- delete the helper formulas.

Comment: This is the solution that I chose to use, very simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

1. Right click the cells in question and select **`Format Cells`**
2. On the number tab select **`Custom`** under the category list
3. Under type add as many spaces as you like before the selected formatting
4. Click OK to close the dialog box
5. Left justify cells to see the added spaces in the cell

This has the added functionality of keeping the cell formatted as number and mathematical formulas will still work.

Comment: Custom format `" "@`. I usually need space at the end so `@" "`.

Answer (score 3):

Select the cells you wish to process and run this small macro:

```
Sub dural()
    For Each r In Selection
    With r
        .Value = "' " & .Text
    End With
    Next r
End Sub
```