# Describe This VBA Code (Adding a space in MS Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel

REFERENCE POST = [Adding a space to the beginning of every cell in excel](https://superuser.com/questions/935249/adding-a-space-to-the-beginning-of-every-cell-in-excel)

Can someone walk this newbie VBA programmer through the parts of this code?

Specifically, which part defines the number of preceding spaces the user/programmer designer is desiring?

Let's say 79 seventy-nine spaces are required to precede the text string.

```
Sub dural()
    For Each r In Selection
    With r
        .Value = "' " & .Text
    End With
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry folks! I am not sure how to format the code sample!

Comment: You see the space in `"' "`? That's the space.

Comment: Nothing in the supplied code determines a number of spaces, just one space

Comment: Do you need to have 79 spaces, or do you need some text to be aligned to the right of a column that is 80 characters wide?

Comment: Yep, just click on that part that @AndrewMorton noted and hit that space key 78 more times. Later when you are tired of trying to figure out if you had 79 or 78 spaces in there, learn to create a loop that will add however many spaces you want.

Comment: I see and thank each one of you. The purpose of this task  is to add 20 to 80 lines of code containing both an X and Y component to define each of hundreds of 2D profiles defined by each point. The application uses only text -based support/data files and coordinate data aligns/starts at position 80 in their example - number of spaces is not critical just following the format ( No tabs are allowed.). 

QUESTION

Comment: Oops, here is the…
QUESTION : So, for the big finale, I will test the ‘spaced out’ < grin> strings from Excel, pasting them into the text file. Now, let’s see if the predefined spaces are honored. Gasp! ‘til Tuesday

Answer (score 0):

*You may use this VBA Code as Module.*

```
    Sub InsertSpacesBeforeText()

    Dim r As Range
    Dim spaces As String
    
    ' Creates 79 spaces

    spaces = String(79, " ")
    
    For Each r In Selection
        If Not r.HasFormula And r.Value <> "" Then

            ' Inserts spaces before the text in the cell

            r.Value = spaces & r.Value
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

---

**N.B.** This `If Not r.HasFormula And r.Value <> "" Then` checks that selected Range don't have formula or are not blank,,, so check before you RUN this code.

Comment: Rajesh, Thank you for the code module. I am re-entering the world of VBA and am starting with the basics… again. So, to make sure I understand: I must run this code in a blank range of cells only. Correct? I prefer to have the code shift the coordinate entries to the right 79 spaces for the user selected range - say for example,  30 rows of coordinates. Is this possible?

Comment: @Chill2U ,,, no this code will only work when the selected data range has some text/data and t 79 spaces will be adder before the data in cells as you have mentioned "precede the text string" !! If the selected Cell /data range is blank the modify this line `If Not r.HasFormula And r.Value <> "" ` with `If Not r.HasFormula And r.Value = "" `

Comment: Thank you Rajesh.

Comment: @Chill2U  ,, if the code I've is working for U then U may UP Vote it as well as Answer too  ☺

Comment: I appreciate your replies. I am new here and unsure how to UP Vote. Also, to answer, I choose the Answer button. Correct?

Comment: @Chill2U  ,,,, Check this page in case you wanna to up vote or accept my post a answer https://superuser.com/tour ,